# I can run tcpdump on the router, but how can I decoding the traffic real-time?

Tags: http, https, network-programming, wireshark

We develop APPs, and sometimes we want to see the traffic of the APP.

Now we use Charles, AnyProxy, or Fiddler, but all these tools need manually settings on the Mobile Device, and not easily to share the traffic.

So I am thinking about a solution: 
1. on the router run tcpdump, or make a port-traffic-mirror to a specific machine, so I can get all the traffic
2. there will be a program, decoding the traffic stream to pure http/https package, and show them on a webpage.
3. anyone who want to see the http/https(based on the APP, or may be protobuf) requests and responses. and can do some search or filter.
4. yes, these works like Wireshark, but how to make Wireshark run on a web?

Comment: Just output the result of `tcpdump -v port 80` into a `<pre>` block?  Pipe into a database and take it out with some web framework.  There are some 2k different web frameworks out there.  Then again, you probably shouldn't make all packet data available over the internet.  Seriously, you do not want people looking at someone else's cookies for an example.